Ender 3 Pro with BigTreeTech runout sensor and CR Touch clicking
My Ender 3 Pro is clicking when printing and retracting and the filament moves but when coming out there are periods of no filament and when retracting, it just pops back in. I also observed that with each click, the runout sensor moved.
I have tried mounting the runout sensor so that it can’t move, but it just ends up breaking off and moving. I also tried glue.
The runout sensor is installed between the extruder and the filament feeder.



I've cleaned it up a bit, but it is not very clear. Add photos, or a link to a YouTube video please. This does sound like a broken extruder lever or something else with the extruder.
